# Ruby and Cucumber - Refactoring a long list of actions

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara

I'm very much a newbie to Ruby and Cucumber automation and I'm trying to automate a basic game at the moment.

The game has around 200 products and I'm running a test that checks each of these one by one to see if the product is enabled.

```
  prod1 = check_product '#product1.product'
  prod1.click unless prod1.nil?
  prod2 = check_product '#product2.product'
  prod2.click unless prod2.nil?
  prod3 = check_product '#product3.product'
  prod3.click unless prod3.nil?
```

My questions is that I don't want to list 200 lines of code representing the products. I feel like I should just be able to just have one line of code with 'x' replacing the product number and tell it to replace x with 1..200.

Something like :-

```
x = 1..200
      prod[x] = check_product '#product[x].product'
      prod[x].click unless prod[x].nil?
```

I know this is horribly wrong, but I hope it demonstrates what I mean.

Is there a good way to do what I'm asking?

Apologies for the probably very basic question and terrible code. I really am just learning the ropes at the moment :-)

=====

To Update the solution below worked a treat. My code now reads :-

```
def product_skips_check
  n = 9
  products = []
  (0..n).each do |i|
  products[i] = check_product "#product#{i}.product"
  products[i].click unless products[i].nil?
  end
end
```

Thanks very much for all replies :-)

Answer (score 1):

If the check_product method accepts a String, you can use interpolation.  In a double quoted String everything inside `#{}` is interpreted and executed as normal ruby code, and the result is converted to a String using its to_s method.

```
n = 300
products = []
(0..n).each do |i|
  products[i] = check_product "#product#{i+1}.product"
  products[i].click unless prod[i].nil?
end
```

Be sure to use double quotes though, interpolation doesn't work in single-quoted strings.

EDIT: changed the code to make a bit more sense

Comment: If it worked for you @JackMarshall-Arts, please can you accept my answer by clicking the tick below the votes?  Thanks!